# Retrieving data from Oracle database installed in AWS server is slower

Tags: java, oracle, performance, amazon-web-services, hibernate

My application is connected to Oracle database installed in an AWS server to operate on data.

My code base is Java/Hibernate and I am using eclipse.

When connecting to AWS, it is really really slow. Even to retrieve even a single row of data it is taking a long time.

Any suggestions on how it can be resolved?

I also have the same database installed in a server (which is not AWS) and it works really fast.

Any suggestions why connecting to/ retrieving from database in AWS server is slower?

Comment: what's the network latency from where your java app is running and where your database is?

Comment: could you specify networking setup? latency? server spec?